# Java Method Stub

Tags: java, methods, stub

Teacher proposed these questions:

> Assume that the following is called from a main method, write a method stub for this invocation: `String course = "band";int year = 2016;printRoster(course,year)`
>
> Assume that the following is called from a main method, write a method stub for this invocation: `String item = enterDescription();`

With no other information, I am slightly confused on what he wants and means by write a method stub. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub

Comment: I think that you should ask to your teacher what he wants from you... Otherwise, people will waste time trying to guess it.

Answer (score 3):

A method stub, likely referring to a method signature, is comprised of an access type, return type, other keywords, the method name, and its parameters. For example, the method stub for the main method is:

```
public static void main(String[])
```

Your teacher is asking you to use the context of the code snippet to determine what the method stub would look like. For example, if I had a method called like this:

```
int num = getNum();
```

Then I know:

1) This is inside the main method, which is `static`, and so the `getNum` method must also be `static`.

2) the `getNum` method returns an `int` because it is being assigned to that type of variable.

3) No arguments are being passed to `getNum`, so it has no parameters.

As such, I would guess that the method signature for `getNum()` is:

```
static int getNum()
```

This is because I don't know if `getNum` is `public`, `private`, etc.

Hopefully this helps you understand the problem and solve it on your own.

Answer (score -1):

I assume he means that you will need to write a method stub for the calls in the code:

```
String course = "band";
int year = 2016;
printRoster(course, year);
```

And...

```
String item = enterDescription();
```

Therefore...

```
private void printRoster(String course, int year) {
    // For example...
    System.out.println("Course: " + course);
    System.out.println("Year: " + year);
}

private String enterDescription() {
    // Mocked return
    return "foobar";
}
```

Unless he means stub out the code itself, which would then be...

```
private void doSomething() {
    String course = "band";
    int year = 2016;
    printRoster(course, year);
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
    String item = enterDescription();
}
```

I suspect it is the former though.

And NB, if the methods are called from a static context, then they should also be declared as static, unless you're going to instantiate the object on which they will be called first.